# Database entries not shown in the expected order

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, sybase

I have the following table structure in my Sybase database :
`myTable {myId1 ID, myId2 ID, myString String}`

The primary Key is `myId1`, and I have two indexes `index1 {myTable.myId1} ASC` and `index2 {myTable.myId2} ASC`

My table contain three entries : `(1,8,'first line')`, `(2,8,'second line')` & `(3,8,'third line')`.

Why when I execute

```
select * 
from myTable`
```

I get

```
3,8,'third line'
1,8,'first line'
2,8,'second line'
```

instead of

```
1,8,'first line'
2,8,'second line'
3,8,'third line'
```

FYI : **`select * from myTable order by myId1 ASC`** returns the wanted output.

Update : Since the result of `select * from myTable` is random, then why I'm always getting that exact same order each time I execute the query ?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: As you have observed if you want an order you *must* `order by`.

Comment: *Ommmmmm, there's no order unless you request it*

Comment: Rows in a relational database are **not** "sorted". The order of the rows from a select is completely random unless you use an `order by`

Comment: There is no *expected order*, unless a query has an `order by` in the outermost `select`.  Period.

Comment: Regarding your *update*: A Select without *order by* usually returns the result in an order based on internal storage/retrieval and thus it just might *look* random. At least it's not predictable...

Answer (score 2):

You should consider data within a tables as a set which is not sorted.

Answer (score 1):

no database is return values in any order except you explicitly 
use `order by` for ordering it

```
like order by column asc or desc
```

as a result 
`select * from myTable order by myId1 ASC` it returns ordered data because you explicitly called it in ascending order

and the 1st query `select * from myTable` does not return ordered because here you didn't use any explicit ordering

Comment: Thanks for responding :)
Can you tell me why then, in all other tables I have in my database, everytime I make a `Select * from myTableX` they are automatically sorted ASC based on the primaryKey ?

Comment: For an allpages locked table with a clustered index, the data is stored in key order. However you're still getting lucky with a direct 'select *', as depending on the query plan the query could be done in parallel and you may still not always get the data in key order if that is the case.

Always use an order by if you want to guarantee a specific order by.